# XSLT transformation JSON to XML Error "Content is not allowed in prolog"

Tags: json, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I want to transform a JSON file to xml.

java -jar c:\saxon\saxon9he.jar -s:C:json -xsl:C:test.xsl -o:C:xml

XSLT for the transformation:

```
>     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
>     <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
>         <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
>         <xsl:param name="input" select="'../json/test.json'"/>
>         <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
>             <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(unparsed-text($input))" mode="copy"/>
>         </xsl:template>
>         <xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="copy">
>             <xsl:copy>
>                 <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" mode="copy"/>
>             </xsl:copy>
>         </xsl:template>    
>     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

i think the processor expect a XML-file as input. Which processor i have to use or is there an other mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the command line option `-it` you can use to start processing with the named template `xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template"`. Any JSON files you can then pass in as a parameter, as your sample already does in the code, on the command line you would add `input=foo.json` to change/set that global parameter. So don't use `-s` at all but use `-it` (as given) and add the right parameter value for the `input` parameter, either in the code you have or on the command line.